# shorten c# null coalescing with tostring if not null

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm trying to output data from a database call in an aspx page.

I'm checking if the DataTable my Repeater is going over has a DateTime in the StartDate column of the current Row and outputs the date in a nice format.  If the Row doesn't contain a DateTime then it'll be a DBNull.Value and I want the string to just say "never"

The following works, but is very long and calls the DataTable twice, (although it's in memory so the second call probably doesn't matter much to execution speed, it's cluttering up the aspx page and making the code harder to read.)

```
<%# (((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["StartDate"] is DateTime) ? ((DateTime)((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["StartDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t") + ".M." : "never" %>
```

However what I'd like to do is something along the lines of  the following non-working code as it removes the 2nd reference to the DataTable cell:

```
<%# (((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["StartDate"] as DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t") ?? "never" %>
```

Unfortunately the null coalescing operator needs to be run before the ToString as ToString on null is an error, but the null coalescing operator needs to be run after the ToString in order to be returning a string, not a DateTime.

Is there a shorthand way of doing this? It seems like the kind of thing that would be very common.

Comment: Seems like you want `?.ToString(...) ?? "never"`, basically the null conditional operator `?.` will only make the right side call if the left side is not null, if the right side is null it just results in null.

Comment: If you do that, though, you'll get ".M." when it's `null` and it won't coalesce. Include that in the format string and quote it, i.e. `?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t'.M.'") ?? "never"` so you actually get `null` and you have a chance for it to coalesce.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid expression term '.' " when I try this. what am I doing wrong? <%# (((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["StartDate"] as DateTime)?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t'.M.") ?? "never" %>

Comment: I would have thought you could use `(((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["StartDate"] is DateTime date) ? date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t") + ".M." : "never" ` - i.e., use pattern matching

Comment: You might need to parenthesize the whole expression (as if there aren't enough of those already). The WebForms parser may not have been updated to handle `?.` without it. Even Razor won't recognize it when it's bare (e.g. `@something?.ToString()` won't parse the null-propagating operator). You might find that you have to extract the expression to a method and call it a day.

Comment: If I add the variable name to do pattern matching like Matthew Watson suggested I get an error " CS1026: ) expected"  If I try throwing in more parenthesis like madreflection suggests I keep getting "Invalid expression term '.' "

Comment: T.S.'s answer is really the best way to go...  That said, `?.` *is* supported by the WebForms parser (just tried it, in and out of a data-binding context), so there really is a syntax error. You haven't shared the latest (exact) thing you've tried so there's no way to know what's wrong. (If you share it, though, edit the question, don't put it in a comment.)

Comment: Well I tried a couple of different parenthesis around the code from my earlier comment and none of them work.  Would you mind posting your test code as an answer? I'm not sure what I'm missing for the .? operator.

Comment: And neither does anyone else because you're the only one who has seen it in its latest form. My test code is a minimal expression that binds a `DateTime?` property to a `asp:Label` control and uses `?.` and `??` on that property and a fallback value. Your syntax error is related to things specific to what you're doing. All I did was rule out the possibility that `?.` wasn't recognized by the parser. You need to show your expression if you want help with it. Indeed, that warrants a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrote extensions for these things and never again worry

```cs
public string GetStringOrDefault(this DataRow r, string col, string def = "")
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(r[col]))
        return def;

    return r[col].ToString();
}

public string GetDateStringOrDefault(this DataRow r, string col, string format, string def = "")
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(r[col]))
        return def;

    return ((DateTime)r[col]).ToString(format);
}
```

usage

```
<%# ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)).GetDateStringOrDefault("StartDate", "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm t", "never") %>
```